# Sort Divs based on distant child's value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sorting

I have some product listings on a third-party site. All listings are contained in `.listings-list`. I'm trying to sort each `.listing` by the value of the `#BGvalue` div 4 children down in ascending order.

If it matters each div generally has 2-3 divs in it and the total listings can be up to 100 per page. I'm looking to make a button that I can press to do the sorting based on `#BGvalue`.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial and adapt it to my needs: https://riptutorial.com/jquery/example/11477/sorting-elements so my variables don't make sense since I just plopped my values in.

Also, I have jQuery loading so it isn't included here but it works.

I've tried this and it doesn't currently work. Some previous iteration appended just the actual BGValue to the bottom but there was no sort. I've since lost that code.

```
var ascending = true;

var $myColorList= $('#root > div > div > div.marketplace-panel-with-scrollbars > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.listings-area > div.listings-list');
var $colors = $myColorList.find( "#root > div > div > div.marketplace-panel-with-scrollbars > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.listings-area > div.listings-list > div:nth-child(1)" );
var sortList = Array.prototype.sort.bind($colors);

var doSort = function ( ascending ) {
    
    sortList(function ( a, b ) {

        var aText = a.find('#BGvalue')
        var bText = b.find('#BGvalue')

        if ( aText < bText ) {
            return ascending ? -1 : 1;
        }

        if ( aText > bText ) {
            return ascending ? 1 : -1;
        }

        return 0;
    });
    
    $myColorList.append($colors);

};

doSort(ascending);

//tutorial https://riptutorial.com/jquery/example/11477/sorting-elements
//main area holding items   #root > div > div > div.marketplace-panel-with-scrollbars > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.listings-area > div.listings-list
//items to sort             #root > div > div > div.marketplace-panel-with-scrollbars > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.listings-area > div.listings-list > div:nth-child(1)
//sort by                   #BGvalue
```

Here is sample code:

```
<div class="listings-list">
    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing-bg-wrapper>
            <div class="listing-bg">
                <div class"listing-info">
                    <div id="BGvalue">3</div>
                </div>
                <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                <div class"listing-info3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="listings-list">
    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing-bg-wrapper>
            <div class="listing-bg">
                <div class"listing-info">
                    <div id="BGvalue">111</div>
                </div>
                <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                <div class"listing-info3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="listings-list">
    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing-bg-wrapper>
            <div class="listing-bg">
                <div class"listing-info">
                    <div id="BGvalue">80</div>
                </div>
                <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                <div class"listing-info3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="listings-list">
    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing-bg-wrapper>
            <div class="listing-bg">
                <div class"listing-info">
                    <div id="BGvalue">1000</div>
                </div>
                <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                <div class"listing-info3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the expected outcome

```
<div class="listings-list">
    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing-bg-wrapper>
            <div class="listing-bg">
                <div class"listing-info">
                    <div id="BGvalue">3</div>
                </div>
                <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                <div class"listing-info3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="listings-list">
    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing-bg-wrapper>
            <div class="listing-bg">
                <div class"listing-info">
                    <div id="BGvalue">80</div>
                </div>
                <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                <div class"listing-info3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="listings-list">
    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing-bg-wrapper>
            <div class="listing-bg">
                <div class"listing-info">
                    <div id="BGvalue">111</div>
                </div>
                <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                <div class"listing-info3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="listings-list">
    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing-bg-wrapper>
            <div class="listing-bg">
                <div class"listing-info">
                    <div id="BGvalue">1000</div>
                </div>
                <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                <div class"listing-info3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have more opening `div` tags than closing. Can you fix?

Comment: Your HTML uses duplicate `id` attribute values ("BGvalue"). This is not valid in HTML, and influences how selectors (don't) work.

Comment: `$myColorList.append($colors);` assumes that `$myColorList` is a single parent node, and all "colors" are (to become) children of it, but this is not the structure you present in HTML: there you have *n* `$myColorList` elements, each with one child. So if you want to sort, you'll have to sort one level higher. But I cannot be sure as long as you don't fix your HTML.

Comment: Your HTML also has unclosed quotes... Are you there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

- The given HTML has unclosed quotes at each occurrence of `listing-bg-wrapper`
- It has unclosed `div` tags at the top level.
- It has duplicate `id` values ("BGvalue"). This is invalid in HTML. You should use a `class` attribute instead.
- The code seems to assume that `$colors` has elements that share the same parent and that they can be appended to a single container `$myColorList`. But the truth is that `$myColorList` is not one element, and each has its own child. So if you want to sort this list, you'll have to sort the elements in `$myColorList`, not `$colors`. This means the container of the list is the *parent* of `$myColorList`. So I propose you use those jQuery variables for what is 1 level higher in the DOM tree.
- `a.find` will not work, as `a` (and `b`) is not a jQuery object, but a DOM element. So you'll need to first make the jQuery collection with `$(a)`.
- `find` returns a jQuery collect, not a text, so comparing like `aText < bText` will not have the desired effect. You'll need to first get the text, with `.text()` and then convert that text to number.

Not an error, but there is a much easier way to determine the return value of the comparator function, using subtraction.

Here is the corrected HTML (with an additional outer `div`) and JavaScript:

```js
// Simplified selector so it works with the demo HTML:
// .listings-list are the elements to be sorted, not their children.
var $colors = $('div.listings-list'); 
var $myColorList = $colors.parent(); // Container is one level up
var sortList = Array.prototype.sort.bind($colors);

function doSort(ascending) {
    sortList(function (a, b) {
        // Convert to jQuery, get the `.text()` and convert to number (+)
        // Using class selector, no duplicate ID allowed!
        var aText = +$(a).find('.BGvalue').text();
        var bText = +$(b).find('.BGvalue').text();
        // Simple way to define the return value
        return ascending ? aText - bText : bText - aText;
    });
    $myColorList.append($colors);
};

doSort(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> <!-- added this DIV -->
    <div class="listings-list">
        <div class="listing">
            <div class="listing-bg-wrapper">
                <div class="listing-bg">
                    <div class"listing-info">
                        <!-- Use class. No duplicate ID allowed -->
                        <div class="BGvalue">3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                    <div class"listing-info3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="listings-list">
        <div class="listing">
            <div class="listing-bg-wrapper">
                <div class="listing-bg">
                    <div class"listing-info">
                        <div class="BGvalue">111</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                    <div class"listing-info3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="listings-list">
        <div class="listing">
            <div class="listing-bg-wrapper">
                <div class="listing-bg">
                    <div class"listing-info">
                        <div class="BGvalue">80</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                    <div class"listing-info3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="listings-list">
        <div class="listing">
            <div class="listing-bg-wrapper">
                <div class="listing-bg">
                    <div class"listing-info">
                        <div class="BGvalue">1000</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class"listing-info2"></div>
                    <div class"listing-info3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You were exactly right on all fronts. Thanks so much for such a thorough answer. I tried to make it easier by only showing relevant code but then I goofed on everything else.

Also, I'm using Tamper Monkey and forced the duplicate IDs in there forgetting the uniqueness requirement.

I appreciate you. Thanks again!